# How to describe WebSocket interface?

Tags: rest, interface, websocket, swagger

For restful services Swagger is a standardized way to describe the interface. Is there already a way to describe Websocket interfaces?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not at the moment. You may want to join the following discussion about supporting Websocket in the next version of OpenAPI/Swagger spec:

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+Websocket

Comment: Unfortunately OpenAPI considers this out of scope. So, they will not be working on it: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2947

Answer (score 11):

Possibly [ASyncAPI](https://www.asyncapi.com/)? I haven't tried it myself yet, but:

> AsyncAPI provides a specification that allows you to define
>   Message-Driven APIs in a machine-readable format. It’s
>   protocol-agnostic, so you can use it for APIs that work over MQTT,
>   AMQP, WebSockets, STOMP, etc. The spec is very similar to
>   OpenAPI/Swagger so, if you’re familiar with them, AsyncAPI should be
>   easy for you.

Answer (score -3):

What about swagger-socket project?

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-socket

Comment: I had a glance at the project's README and I don't see it answering the question on how to represent Websocket within a Swagger document. Did I miss something?

Comment: Looks like Swagger Socket is not about documentation

Comment: unfortunately now archived and no longer maintained